# OpenCV's Cascade classifier face detect freezing

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I've been working on a face detection script that lets you detect multiple faces at once, using OpenCV's (cv2) Haar Cascade Classifier, yet , every time I call this function , the program freezes indefinitely without showing any sign of error, here's the code of my function:

```
 import cv2
 import cv2.cv
 def detect(img, cascade_fn='haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml',
           scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(20, 20),
           flags=cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE):
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_fn)
    faces = list()
    test = True
    while test == True:
        rect = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=scaleFactor,
                                         minNeighbors=minNeighbors,
                                         minSize=minSize, flags=flags)
        if len(rect) == 0:
            test = False
        else:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rect:
                faces.append(img[y1:y2, x1:x2])
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, (0, 0, 0))
    return faces
```

So please , could anybody point to me the reason I'm facing this error, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `detectMultiScale` won't find any faces, `test` is assigned `False` and the loop ends. If it actually detects faces they get added to the list `faces` and a rectangle is drawn just as you (presumably) intended.

But `test` remains `True`, which means that your loop gets executed again. And since none of its input variables were changed `detectMultiScale` will detect the same faces and again add them to the list `faces`. Hence in this case the loop will never end.

You might want to do this:

```
import cv2
def detect(img, cascade_fn='haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml',
       scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(20, 20),
       flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE):
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_fn)
    faces = list()
    rect = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=scaleFactor,
                                     minNeighbors=minNeighbors,
                                     minSize=minSize, flags=flags)
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rect:
        faces.append(img[y1:y2, x1:x2])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, (0, 0, 0))
    return faces
```